# What are the syntax options for implementing decorators?

Tags: syntax, decorators

In Python, this code is an example of decorators:

```python
@decorator_func
def main_func():
    # Do stuff
```

When `main_func` is called, it will call `decorator_func` with `main_func` as the only argument. It will then call the returned function* instead of `main_func` with the arguments provided.

<sup>*A decorator doesn't have to return a function, but that doesn't really matter.</sup>

Read [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator) for more info on Python decorators.

Anyway, as you can see above, Python uses `@` and then  the decorator function name before the main function definition. Are there any other syntax options for implementing this? And what are their advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Rust/C# Attributes

Rust and C# use similar syntax for their "attribute" feature, which is closer in functionality to Java's annotations but is used in the same manner as decorators syntactically.

Rust:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_foo() {
    /* ... */
}
```

(Rust also allows attributes to be applied to the whole module, using this syntax:)

```rust
#![crate_type = "lib"]
```

C#:

```csharp
[Serializable]
public class SampleClass
{
    // ...
}
```